# What are the underlying basis/mechanism for inattentiveness in ADHD?

Tags: attention, adhd

I have been exploring inattentive ADHD and I am really struggling to understand the difference between clinically significant inattentiveness in people with ADHD versus non-clinically significant inattentiveness.

Are there good explanations and evidence of neurological differences that can help me understand the pathways?

I am not sure whether a discussion about the differences in brain structure would be helpful in elucidating and elaborating the differences.  I could not find anything relevant in this SE, the brain structure differences in hyperactivity has been discussed in this question but nothing really about inattentiveness in ADHD - [Which brain areas are linked to Hyperactivity in ADHD?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/16622/which-brain-areas-are-linked-to-hyperactivity-in-adhd)

Comment: Genetically at least, it seems that ADHD is related to dyslexia: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0098590 But the reward pathway is apparently involved. https://www.webmd.com/add-adhd/news/20090908/adhd-tied-to-brains-reward-pathway

Comment: As discussed in [this brief video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDnZsYGNKzs) alas the pathway studies for the two disorders have mostly ignored this genetic link.

Comment: There is a pretty old study which linked them in terms of brain morphology as well, but also found substantial differences  https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamaneurology/article-abstract/590284